# From hourly DatetimeIndex to daily DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I am trying to convert an **hourly** `DatetimeIndex` to a **daily** `DatetimeIndex` **with no repetitions**.

I have two `DatetimeIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

snapshots = pd.date_range("2050-01-01 00:00", "2050-12-31 23:00", freq="H")

days = pd.date_range("2050-01-01", "2050-12-31", freq="d")
```

However I would like to create `days` directly from `snapshots`. I tried to convert to `PeriodIndex` but then I struggle with unique dates:

```
days = snapshots.to_period().asfreq('d')
```

(I have 'YYYY-MM-DD' data, but 8760 for every hour of the year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpliest is pass minimal and maximal value of `snapshots` to [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
days = pd.date_range(snapshots.min(), snapshots.max(), freq="d")
print (days)
DatetimeIndex(['2050-01-01', '2050-01-02', '2050-01-03', '2050-01-04',
               '2050-01-05', '2050-01-06', '2050-01-07', '2050-01-08',
               '2050-01-09', '2050-01-10',
               ...
               '2050-12-22', '2050-12-23', '2050-12-24', '2050-12-25',
               '2050-12-26', '2050-12-27', '2050-12-28', '2050-12-29',
               '2050-12-30', '2050-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq='D')
```

Or use [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) for set times to `00:00:00` and remove duplicates - by [`Index.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html) or [`Index.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html):

```
days = snapshots.normalize().unique()
print (days)
DatetimeIndex(['2050-01-01', '2050-01-02', '2050-01-03', '2050-01-04',
               '2050-01-05', '2050-01-06', '2050-01-07', '2050-01-08',
               '2050-01-09', '2050-01-10',
               ...
               '2050-12-22', '2050-12-23', '2050-12-24', '2050-12-25',
               '2050-12-26', '2050-12-27', '2050-12-28', '2050-12-29',
               '2050-12-30', '2050-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq=None)
```

---

```
days = snapshots.normalize().drop_duplicates()
print (days)
DatetimeIndex(['2050-01-01', '2050-01-02', '2050-01-03', '2050-01-04',
               '2050-01-05', '2050-01-06', '2050-01-07', '2050-01-08',
               '2050-01-09', '2050-01-10',
               ...
               '2050-12-22', '2050-12-23', '2050-12-24', '2050-12-25',
               '2050-12-26', '2050-12-27', '2050-12-28', '2050-12-29',
               '2050-12-30', '2050-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq=None)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `unique` and `drop_duplicates`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo - If use with `Index` seems same ouput, generally `unique` can call to Series, Index, `drop_duplicates` same + DataFrame

Comment: @Tomerikoo - Added to answer, I got same ouput.

Comment: Yeah I know me too. I'm really asking out of curiosity if there is a meaningful difference as they seem to do the same thing...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - thinking - If call in Series got different ouput - numpy array vs Series

Answer (score 1):

As being an [`Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) object, [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html#pandas.PeriodIndex) has the [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html) method. By the way, [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) takes the frequency as an argument, so you can save one call:

```
days = snapshots.to_period(freq='d').drop_duplicates()
print(days)
```

Gives:

```
PeriodIndex(['2050-01-01', '2050-01-02', '2050-01-03', '2050-01-04',
             '2050-01-05', '2050-01-06', '2050-01-07', '2050-01-08',
             '2050-01-09', '2050-01-10',
             ...
             '2050-12-22', '2050-12-23', '2050-12-24', '2050-12-25',
             '2050-12-26', '2050-12-27', '2050-12-28', '2050-12-29',
             '2050-12-30', '2050-12-31'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=365)
```